# Close primefaces dialog and redirect main page

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, primefaces

In a submit handler of a button, I sometimes have to close my `p:dialog` and immediately perform of redirect of the main page. I have tried below code

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(id);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .redirect("../quote/select.xhtml?prospectid=" + id);
```

This is contained in submit(), called via a simple `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.common_save}" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

Unfortunately, this does the redirect within the dialog, and does not close the dialog itself.
Using only the first line does close my dialog, but then of course I still need to redirect my page.

Is there any way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you show xhtml code? It's not clear how you call the managed bean.

Comment: Edited, nothing special though, just a p:commandButton triggering an ajax submit. Note that I tried with a h:commandButton as well, giving the same result.

Comment: If you are going to redirect anyway, why to care if you closed the dialog or not ?

Comment: Because, when you're redirecting with the dialog open, you are only doing a redirect of the iframe displayed in the dialog. And that is exactly what I do not need, as described in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok If I get you correctly you are calling your bean through action property. This is not ususal way to go. Check the following example:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" resizable="false" header="Dialog">
    <!-- Dialog controls here -->
    <!-- ... -->

    <h:panelGroup>
    <p:commandButton value="Close and redirect" actionListener="#{bean.closeListener}"  action="/main" />
    <p:commandButton value="Just close" onclick="PF('dlg').hide()"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:dialog>
```

'actionListener' property is used to execute any code behind this event.
'action' property is used here to set dialog outcome - this can be .xhtml page name (you can omit extention) or it can be EL expression refering bean method returning String. 
In the example above rediretcion will go to   main.xhtml page located in WebContent root.

In general, 'actionListener' is executed first, then outcome is evalueted and jsf view changed to evaluated page.

Answer (score 1):

if you are still looking for the answer then I think I have done the same thing that you need.
Excuse Me for bad formatting

here is the code for editor.xhtml file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:x="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
 <f:view>

<h:head>
    <title>Editor and dialog!</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">

        <p:commandButton value="Edit Content" type="button" onclick="dlg2.show();" style="color:green;font-size:10px;"/>


    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" >
        <h:outputText value="Edit Content here" style="color:green"/>
        <h:form>
        <p:growl id="message" showDetail="true" />
        <p:editor value="#{editorBean.value}" widgetVar="editContent" ></p:editor>
        <p:commandButton value="Publish"  action="editor?faces-redirect=true" update="message" onclick="dlg2.hide();">
            <p:confirmDialog header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        </p:commandButton>


        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>   
    <div >
        <h:outputText  value="#{editorBean.value}"></h:outputText>
    </div>


</h:body>
  </f:view>
 </html>
```

And this is the code for the bean class I have named it as EditorBean.java

```
package com.dev;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.CloseEvent;


@ManagedBean(name="editorBean")
public class EditorBean {  

  private static String value;  
  //private static String outValue;


public EditorBean() {


}

public void addMessage(String summary, String detail) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, detail);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}


public String getValue() {  
    System.out.println("getValue()"+value);
    return value;  
}  



public void setValue(String value) { 
    System.out.println("setValue()"+value);
    addMessage("System Error", value+"! Please try again later.");
    this.value = value;  
    //getOutValue();
}

/*public String getOutValue() {
    this.outValue = value;
    System.out.println("getOutValue()"+outValue);
    return outValue;
}*/




}
```